# If $a^2 = 0$ then $a+1$ and $a-1$ are invertible.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Prove that this is true in a nontrivial ring with unity.

If $a^2 = 0$ then $a+1$ and $a-1$ are invertible.

I've seen a few examples and tried out the following solution.

Since $a^2 = 0$:

1 = 1 - $a^2$ = $(1-a)(1+a)$

But I'm not sure if that proves the question. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Your idea is correct.

Comment: Why are you not sure?  This shows that $1-a$ and $1+a$ are each other's inverses.

Comment: But does it matter that its $1-a$ instead of $a-1$? Aren't those not the same thing?

Comment: You have actually the equivalence, even when the ring is not commutative (because of the definition of element identity $e*x=x*e=x$)
$$(1-a)(1+a)=1\iff a^2=0$$